# How to check the return value of UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to check if the user click "yes" for example I want to put a certain action.

This is my line of code:

```
UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"this will start a new game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    [mes show];
```

So I want to say `if user tap "yes" preform this action`

this is my method: I want to say if the user click "yes" create the new game.

```
- (IBAction)newGame:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"this will start a new game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    [mes show];


    self.flipsCount = 0;
    self.game = nil;
    for (UIButton *button in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:button]];
        card.unplayble = NO;
        card.faceUp = NO;
        button.alpha = 1;
    }

    self.notificationLabel.text = nil;
    [self updateUI];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826659/uialertview-delegates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
     if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        //User clicked ok
        NSLog(@"ok");
       [self newGame:[UIButton alloc] ];
    }
    else
    {
        //User clicked cancel
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

it takes ButtonIndex values from left to right .

Comment: how do `if` only on the yes or no buttons? like `if (cancelButtonTitle.selcted) do something` @sunny

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method of `UIAlertView` as

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (buttonIndex == 1)//Yes
   {
       self.flipsCount = 0;
       self.game = nil;
       for (UIButton *button in self.cardButtons) 
       {
            Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:button]];
            card.unplayble = NO;
            card.faceUp = NO;
            button.alpha = 1;
       }

       self.notificationLabel.text = nil;
       [self updateUI];
   }
   else//No 
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following method in the same class (or in the class you have set as `delegate`):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
    //User clicked ok
  }
  else
  {
    //User clicked cancel
  }
}
```