# Show Next Screen Only After User Closes Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working on a losing screen and I'd like to let users view their game before showing the stats screen. I've decided to use an alert to show users the current screen. After they hit OK, they should be taken to the stats screen.

The problem is, the stat screen pops up at the same time as the alert. How can I make sure the stats screen opens after the user closes the alert?

```
if ([self.model userHasLost]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"You lost..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  [self _showGameEndScreenWitnWin:NO]; //Stats screen should open after alert is closed
}
```

Comment: You should use the delegate methods of UIAlertView. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-uialertview-and-uialertviewdelegate--mobile-3159

Comment: @Sunnyshah That really should be an answer and not a comment

Comment: @JustSid if i given an answer then may be he will copy and paste. the best thing is that he would know about the delegate methods. if he found something then he will automatically know the answer

Comment: @Sunnyshah Then why be on StackOverflow to begin with if you don't want to answer people?

Comment: according to me only answer is not a only enough. the best thing user understand the whole thing. in my comment i have givena link so he will understand about UIAlertView and its delegate methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the alert view delegate. In this example self will conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.

```
if ([self.model userHasLost]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"You lost..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}
```

You can then listen to a delegate method for when the alert view is dismissed :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

      [self _showGameEndScreenWitnWin:NO]; //Stats screen should open after alert is closed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delegate method of `UIAlertView` and also need to set `delegate` of `UIAlertView = self`,

Following is `delegate` method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

check `buttonIndex` in this method it's give you `NSInteger` and manage click of button.

For more information read this [UIAlertView Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826659/uialertview-delegates).

Answer (score 1):

For this situation need to use delegate method, 
For simple Example Refer Here: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIAlertView.html